# How to convert list of dictionaries into Pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert my list of dictionaries into DataFrame. This is the list:

```
mylist = 
[
  {"type_activity_id":1,"type_activity_name":"xxx"},
  {"type_activity_id":2,"type_activity_name":"yyy"},
  {"type_activity_id":3,"type_activity_name":"zzz"}
]
```

This is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame(mylist, StringType())

df.show(2,False)

+-----------------------------------------+
|                                    value|
+-----------------------------------------+
|{type_activity_id=1,type_activity_id=xxx}|
|{type_activity_id=2,type_activity_id=yyy}|
|{type_activity_id=3,type_activity_id=zzz}|
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I assume that I should provide some mapping and types for each column, but I don't know how to do it.

**Update:**

I also tried this:

```
schema = ArrayType(
    StructType([StructField("type_activity_id", IntegerType()),
                StructField("type_activity_name", StringType())
                ]))
df = spark.createDataFrame(mylist, StringType())
df = df.withColumn("value", from_json(df.value, schema))
```

But then I get `null` values:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
| null|
| null|
+-----+
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do it like this. You will get a dataframe with 2 columns.

```
mylist = [
  {"type_activity_id":1,"type_activity_name":"xxx"},
  {"type_activity_id":2,"type_activity_name":"yyy"},
  {"type_activity_id":3,"type_activity_name":"zzz"}
]

myJson = sc.parallelize(mylist)
myDf = sqlContext.read.json(myJson)
```

Output :

```
+----------------+------------------+
|type_activity_id|type_activity_name|
+----------------+------------------+
|               1|               xxx|
|               2|               yyy|
|               3|               zzz|
+----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: @Markus If `mylist` is an rdd. You can do `spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(mylist))`

Comment: unfortunately, it fails with "_corrupt_record" for some records

Comment: for example records with None 
{'fail' : None}

Answer (score 39):

In the past, you were able to simply pass a dictionary to `spark.createDataFrame()`, but this is now deprecated:

```python
mylist = [
  {"type_activity_id":1,"type_activity_name":"xxx"},
  {"type_activity_id":2,"type_activity_name":"yyy"},
  {"type_activity_id":3,"type_activity_name":"zzz"}
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(mylist)
#UserWarning: inferring schema from dict is deprecated,please use pyspark.sql.Row instead
#  warnings.warn("inferring schema from dict is deprecated,"
```

As this warning message says, you should use `pyspark.sql.Row` instead.

```python
from pyspark.sql import Row
spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in mylist).show(truncate=False)
#+----------------+------------------+
#|type_activity_id|type_activity_name|
#+----------------+------------------+
#|1               |xxx               |
#|2               |yyy               |
#|3               |zzz               |
#+----------------+------------------+
```

Here I used `**` ([keyword argument unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)) to pass the dictionaries to the `Row` constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why it was deprecated?

Comment: I am not sure why. As an aside, this is probably faster than converting to/from json.

Comment: But this may not work when the structure of each dictionary (array element) is not same.

Comment: Using the `spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in mylist)` method in PySpark 3.0.0, I'm getting downstream issues where values are placed in the wrong columns. Possibly related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26200

Comment: how to make sure the values in dict are of correct type, or typecast them if neccssary?

Answer (score 5):

in Spark Version 2.4 it is possible to do directly with 
df=spark.createDataFrame(mylist)

```
>>> mylist = [
...   {"type_activity_id":1,"type_activity_name":"xxx"},
...   {"type_activity_id":2,"type_activity_name":"yyy"},
...   {"type_activity_id":3,"type_activity_name":"zzz"}
... ]
>>> df1=spark.createDataFrame(mylist)
>>> df1.show()
+----------------+------------------+
|type_activity_id|type_activity_name|
+----------------+------------------+
|               1|               xxx|
|               2|               yyy|
|               3|               zzz|
+----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: It still gives me this warning though `UserWarning: inferring schema from dict is deprecated,please use pyspark.sql.Row instead`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue when creating `dataframe` from list of dictionaries.
I have resolved this using `namedtuple`.

Below is my code using data provided.

```
from collections import namedtuple
final_list = []
mylist = [{"type_activity_id":1,"type_activity_name":"xxx"},
          {"type_activity_id":2,"type_activity_name":"yyy"}, 
          {"type_activity_id":3,"type_activity_name":"zzz"}
         ]
ExampleTuple = namedtuple('ExampleTuple', ['type_activity_id', 'type_activity_name'])

for my_dict in mylist:
    namedtupleobj = ExampleTuple(**my_dict)
    final_list.append(namedtupleobj)

sqlContext.createDataFrame(final_list).show(truncate=False)
```

output

```
+----------------+------------------+
|type_activity_id|type_activity_name|
+----------------+------------------+
|1               |xxx               |
|2               |yyy               |
|3               |zzz               |
+----------------+------------------+
```

my version informations are as follows

```
spark: 2.4.0
python: 3.6
```

It is not necessary to have `my_list` variable. since it was available I have used it to create namedtuple object otherwise directly `namedtuple` object can be created.